# Symfony2 doctrine DQL Join - no results for some cases, but results with sql

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, dql

I got verry strange problem with dql.

I have two tables connecter with foreign key:

```
== Table incident ==
id, cycle_nr, ...
1,  1
2,  3

== Table incident_active ==
id, incident_id, user_id, ...
1,  1,           1
...
```

I need to show active incidents for some cycles and everything is fine if I do mySQL query lilke this:

```
SELECT * FROM `incident_active` LEFT JOIN incident ON incident.id = `incident_active`.incident_id WHERE cycle_nr <= 2 and user_id = 1
```

Same query in DQL works too, but only for cycle_nr != 2

```
SELECT incidentActive, incident 
            FROM AccountingBundle:IncidentActive incidentActive 
            JOIN incidentActive.incident incident
            WHERE incidentActive.company_id = 1 AND incident.cycle_nr <= 2
```

For cycle_nr <= 2 i get an empty result. I guess because of the abscense of incident for this cycle, but I'm asking <=2 and not == 2. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The default join in DQL is INNER JOIN. Those queries are not equivalent.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `incident_active`
LEFT JOIN incident ON incident.id = `incident_active`.incident_id
WHERE cycle_nr <= 2 and user_id = 1
```

This SQL query is written in DQL like this (assuming the user is an entity)

```sql
SELECT incidentActive, incident 
FROM AccountingBundle:IncidentActive incidentActive 
LEFT JOIN incidentActive.incident incident
WHERE incident.cycle_nr <= :cycleNr
  AND incidentActive.user = :userId
```

Also, when you have conditions just for the join and don't want it to affect the results from "main" table, you should add them to that join conditions only, like this.

```sql
SELECT incidentActive, incident 
FROM AccountingBundle:IncidentActive incidentActive 
LEFT JOIN incidentActive.incident incident WITH incident.cycle_nr <= :cycleNr
WHERE incidentActive.user = :userId
```

With bound parameters it should look like this, given the above query is in `$dql`.

```php
$result = $em->createQuery($dql)
    ->setParameter('cycleNr', 2)
    ->setParameter('userId', 1)
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I forgot about LEFT JOIN indeed. And now I get results(IncidentActive object) for the query, but an empty incident. What I don't understand, because the incident is there(in DB). Maybe my mapping is wrong?